# Trying to combine INSERT and SELECT queries in MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to combine SELECT and INSERT queries, but with no luck. The below query works well..

```
INSERT INTO counts (count)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `twitter` WHERE created_local > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE AND text LIKE '%USDJPY%'
```

My DB columns that I do INSERT query are "pair" and "count".

In above query the count is inserted into the counts table > count column but I am also trying to insert in the above case "USDJPY", tried different combinations but all end up with sql error.

I would appriciate a feedback...

Answer (score 1):

Just select a constant for the literal value you want to insert.  And also, please specify all column names which are being targeted by your insert.

```
INSERT INTO counts (pair, count)
SELECT 'USDJPY', COUNT(*)
FROM twitter
WHERE created_local > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE AND text LIKE '%USDJPY%';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.  It worked finally.